# Complex Spotfire Join

Tags: left-join, inner-join, spotfire, join

I am attempting a complex join. I have tried a Left Outer, Left Single, Full, Inner, Right Outer and Right Single and none of them have produced the result I need. 
I feel it might be easier to explain with Pictures so here it goes. In Pic 1 you can see my main Data Table **Total Sales_2**.

What I want to do is bring in the Value column from  **ROI RUBU Schema** see Pic 2 for the corresponding Product on the corresponding Schema into **Total Sales_2**

So in Pic 1 you can see I have a line highlighted in green. It has its account number **TY00009**, its Schema Name **ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8**, the product number **156118**, the product name, **Estrumate 1x20ml 195**,  the Qty **10** and the Total Value **424.50** 
what I would like to see in the next column in **Total Sales_2** is Value and 0.20 but I don't get that see Pic 3

I have used and a Left Outer join in this example placed on the Product code to bring in the Value Column from **ROI RUBU Schema** see Pic 2 into **Total Sales_2**

I was expecting to see 0.20 as I have a line highlighted in green in Pic 2 because **ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8** gives back 0.20 for product **156118**

As you can see in Pic 3 I get different values back for Product **156118** on **ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8** See Pic 3

What I need is the value to be 0.20 for all on Product **156118** on the account TY00009 because its on **ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8**

If TY00009 was on **ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_9** I would expect to see 0.27 for Product **156118** as that is what **ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_9** gives back on Product **156118** again see Pic 2 **ROI RUBU Schema**

I have tried every join there is available and no luck. If anyone can offer any help it would be greatly appreciated.

Pic 1
[image]

Pic 2
[image]

Pic 3
[image]

So based on feedback from an administrator please find what I believe to be a useful amount of data that can be used to recreate what I am currently facing. If more data is needed I am happy to supply

**Total Sales_2 Data**

```
Customer Maxx name  Customer Maxx Code  Schema Name Product Code    Product Description Sold Quantity   Total Value
Random Customer Name    TY00009 ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8   156118  Estrumate 1x20ml 195    10  424.5
Random Customer Name    TY00009 ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8   119977  Rotavec Corona 1x40ml 125   30  5222
Random Customer Name    TY00009 ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8   30179   Bovilis BVD 1x25ds 195  3   424.5
Random Customer Name    TY00009 ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8   21406   Delvosteron 1x20ml 125  6   5222
Random Customer Name    TY00009 ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8   13262   Dexafort 1x50ml 195 4   5222
Random Customer Name    TY00009 ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8   156118  Estrumate 1x20ml 195    12  4444
Random Customer Name    TY00009 ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8   119977  Rotavec Corona 1x40ml 125   32  3333
```

**ROI RUBU Schema Data**

```
Product Number  Product Name    List Price Oct 1st 2018 Category    Value
156118  Estrumate 1x20ml 100    €28.50  ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8   0.2
156118  Estrumate 1x20ml 100    €28.50  ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_9   0.27
156118  Estrumate 1x20ml 100    €28.50  ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_10  0.16
```

Comment: what columns are you using to join the tables?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Hi drxl: I am using the Product Code to join the tables. Thank you for the help

Comment: @philipxy: thank you for the feedback and yes I see now that a sample of usable data is a far superior way to go than pictures. I will try to get some usable data on the question to make it easier for the community to answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got there, and I wanted to give the answer so that it may help others.

It was simple really and silly on my part. It was a left outer join that was needed, but I only bought in 1 Column **Value** from the **ROI RUBU Schema** table, so when I saw all the different values for **ROI_RUBU_SCHEMA_8** on data table **Total Sales_2 Data** i thought the join was wrong. 
If I had of also bought in the Category Column from **ROI RUBU Schema** table into **Total Sales_2** I would of seen all the possible Schema. I simply did not bring in Category Column from  **ROI RUBU Schema** table. Silly but it happened :-)